# Google Cloud Message and Android version

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to implement `Google Cloud Messaging` in in my app which only runs with `Android 2.2` and above.This includes modifying the Manifest file.

If my app is to run at `Android 2.1`, it immediately shows a force close dialog.
May I know how do stop this from happening?

Currently possible solutions:

1. Maintain 2 different version of apk in Google Play Publisher (I haven't tried this, but it seems to have more works)
2. Use GCM alternative?

I wish my App can support Android 2.1 onwards, and only show a warning message to user e.g "to use this feature you have get Android 2.2 and above" in particular Activity that runs GCM.

Answer (score 3):

If your app can function without GCM as well, then you should register for GCM only if version is 2.2 or higher. I guess the following lines are throwing exception in "fail-fast" manner.

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Android version of Device that your App is running in it:

- Since: API Level 4

  ```
  android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT
  ```
- Since: API Level 1 (`This is deprecated.`)

  ```
  android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK
  ```

**Edit**:
When you know Android version of device,you can decide in first Activity that App has to run normally or must show a message for user.

You can also check Android documentation about `Application backward compatibility`.